# Unable to delete Knowledgebase from QnA Maker

Tags: azure, azure-qna-maker

From Azure portal,I have deleted App Services, webapp bot, etc respective of the resource group.(Main agenda as cleaning Unnecessary files from portal). There is no App service respective of the KB.

Now, I am unable to delete Knowledge-base from QnA maker. while deleting the KB,I am getting the bellow error. please guide me how to delete the KB
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Creating QnA service creates the following resources

1. App Service Plan
2. App Service
3. Search Service
4. Cognitive Services
5. Application Insights

If you delete all the above resources, your related Knowledge-base should be deleted automatically.

Most probably, you had your KB opened in the browser before deleting your resources. So, when you hit "Delete" now after resources were removed, the QnA Maker cannot find the back-end services.

Accordingly, if you refresh your browser you will not find your KB

**Update**

To clarify how to recognize resources related to your knowledge base, let's assume your knowledge base deployment host is `https://qnaappservice1.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker`, this means the following

- The associated AppService name is `qnaappservice1`
- The associated SearchService name is `qnaappservice1-[Random postfix]` like `aspvv5ocgc7gucy`.

The remaining resources will be named based on you QnA Service. For example, if your QnA Service is named `qnaservice1`, your remaining resources will be as follows:

- App Service Plan will be `qnaservice1`
- Cognitive Service will be `qnaservice1`
- Application Insights will be `qnaservice1-ai`

Comment: Thank you for response,  can I able to identify which are the file names/files (App service , App service plan, Application insights, Search, Congnitive service) using my KB? if yes, it could be useful to delete my KB.

Comment: From QnA Maker, click your KB settings, under deployment details you will see the Host value=https://[AppServiceName]..azurewebsites.net/qnamaker. This placeholder should be the name of all related resources

Comment: Thank you for updates,My KB  hot as 'https://vs2017-azure-bot-demo.azurewebsites.net/qnamaker'. according your above point my app service name as 'vs2017-azure-bot-demo'.  Unfortunately unable to identify the Appservice name in Azure portal. in this scenario how can I delete my KB

Comment: This indicates you have already deleted the app service but haven't delete the rest of related resources. I have edited my answer again as I remembered you might have given your QnA service a different name than the AppService name, please check